# Automatically give permissions to users for each build of TestFlight app

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, testflight

When building our iOS application via Jenkins, and uploading from the TestFlight plugin, I have to go to TestFlight to give permissions to the same list of users for every single build. In a Dev environment (where there are multiple builds per day), this is very annoying.

Since it's the same distribution list of users every time, can I default the permissions to that list of users for every single build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a distribution list for the Jenkins TestFlight plugin (it's hidden under Advanced in the configuration).

These distribution lists are created in the People tab on TestFlight.